# XQuery - is it possible to generate non-XML document?

Tags: xml, xquery

I would like to use XQuery to generate Java source code from my XML document, for instance:

```
<configuration package="my.package.name">

    <property>
        <name>First</name>
        <value>0</value>
        <description>First description</description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>Second</name>
        <value>2</value>
        <description>Second description</description>
    </property>
...
```

Should generate:

```
package my.package.name;

class MyClass {
    // First description
    private String first;

    // Second description
    private String second;
}
```

I was trying to start like this:

```
xquery version "1.0";

"package "+$doc/@package
"class "+$doc/@classname
{
for $property in $doc//property
    return {
        "private String "+$property/name::text()
    }
}
```

The syntax is obviously incorrect and I wonder whether it is even feasible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details depend a bit on your query processor. It should be possible to return a query result as a string, and it may also be possible to use the text serialization method as in XSL; but the way you invoke this varies from one query processor to another. (The difference between the two approaches is that the text serialization method will automatically turn anything in the query result into a string, and then concatenate the strings).

Here's how to do it in the form of a query returning a single string:

```
declare variable $nl "= '&#10;';
concat(
  "package ", $doc/@package, $nl,
  "class ", $doc/@classname, $nl,
  string-join(
    (for $property in $doc//property
     return {
        concat("private String ", $property/name)
     }), $nl)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

XQuery:

```
declare function xf:XML2Java($configuration as element(configuration))
    as xs:string {
    let $package := string($configuration/@package)
    let $newline := "&#13;"
       for $property in $configuration/property
       let $variable := data($property/name)
       let $javadoc := data($property/description)
       return
        fn:concat($package,$newline,"class MyClass{",$newline,"//",$javadoc,$newline,"private String ",$variable,";",$newline," }")     
};
```

Input:

```
<configuration package="com.test">
    <property>
        <name>Test</name>
        <value>somevalue</value>
        <description>This is test variable</description>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Output:

```
com.test
class MyClass{
//This is test variable
private String Test;
 }
```

Did this in WebLogic workshop XQuery designer.