# xquery output as markdown table

Tags: markdown, xquery

I know how to output x-query results in HTML format, *see e.g.* [XQuery to HTML table: generating columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66904042/xquery-to-html-table-generating-columns)

But I could not find a single example on the internet to output in markdown table. (Xquery version 1.0 preferred)

```
id | lname | fname
===| ===== | =====
32 | Doe   | John
43 | Row   | Jane
```

I do not want the output as HTML to be converted to markdown, nor using any script (e.g Bash).

So far, I have been able to create the rows for the markdown table, but not the header of the table

```
for $i in doc("source.xml")//employees
return
string-join(($i/id, $i/lname, $i/fname), "|")
```

I tried to follow the instructions on this link, but I failed. [XQuery - is it possible to generate non-XML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394267/xquery-is-it-possible-to-generate-non-xml-document?newreg=a6dd9990223d4f5dacd816418cb912cd)

Comment: Markdown is a text format, so, if you know the right format, just create/output the required text. Or do you expect the XQuery engine to have some support built-in for Markdown output? I doubt that is the case, particularly if you are looking at (old) XQuery 1 engines, but anyway, if you use a particular engine, look at its documentation if there is some support for Markdown output.

Comment: eXist-db seems to have a module to **parse** markdown https://github.com/eXist-db/exist-markdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So somehow along the lines of

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method "text";

string-join(
  (
    string-join(('id', 'last name', 'first name'), '|'),
    string-join(('--', '--', '--'), '|'),
    for $emp in //employee return string-join(($emp/id, $emp/lname, $emp/fname), '|')
  ),
  '&#10;'
)
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. My failure was due to a trick that I did not notice in Michael Kay answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394267/xquery-is-it-possible-to-generate-non-xml-document?newreg=a6dd9990223d4f5dacd816418cb912cd  , and in fact I did not know before.  I needed to add  '&#10;' at the end of the first string-joint function for the new-line. Here is  a more explanation on special characters for the folks like me: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery/Special_Characters

Comment: With the upcoming version 4 of XQuery, you'll be able to write `char('\n')` instead of `&#10;`.